# Php7.1-fpm php.ini not changing at all

Tags: php, nginx

When I code this in my php file:

```
echo php_ini_loaded_file();
```

The output is : 
/etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini

Then I edit the php.ini

```
sudo nano /etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini
```

And change my memory_limit to 256M, upload_max_filesize from 2M to 10M, post_max_filesize from 8M to 10M,

then I exit and I run

```
sudo service php7.1-fpm restart
sudo /etc/init.d/php7.1-fpm restart
sudo service nginx restart
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

Then I see my `phpinfo()`, my memory limit, upload max filesize and post max filesize not changing at all..

I turned off my computer then I turn on it again, and check my phpinfo(), it's still not changing..

May I know what should I do to change them, please?

Answer (score 0):

You must configure **nginx** to forward the requests to the PHP FastCGI processor (php-fpm). An example configuration can be found at [Nginx PHP-FPM](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/#connecting-nginx-to-php-fpm)

After configuring, restart both services to take effect.

Comment: I had added "fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;" in my /etc/nginx/sites-available/default configuration, but takes no effect: 

https://codeshare.io/ayZeJq  

And I ensure I have restarted both nginx and php7.1-fpm.. 

Is this right?

Comment: Please paste the output of <?php var_export($_SERVER); ?> and <?php phpinfo(); ?> to understand what is happening behind and the distro you are using.

Comment: Also, it is recommended to use systemd to control the service(s) life cycle. For ex: I would do "sudo systemctl restart php7.1-fpm" to restart the php7.1-fpm service.

Comment: What should I see in <?php var_export($_SERVER); ?> 
? 

phpinfo() still says that my max_upload_files is 2M, although my php.ini in php fpm is changed..

Comment: What should I check in <?php var_export($_SERVER); ?> ?